# Какой падеж употребить?

Tags: синтаксис

Пишу задачи для олимпиады и споткнулась на фразе: **"Рамка не имеет форму прямоугольника"**. Как правильно: "форму" или "формы". Если бы не отрицание, было бы ясно.

Кстати, а этот вопрос относится к синтаксису или к морфологии? Как-то они у меня путаются. Но думаю все же к синтаксису.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего - к стилистике. Оба варианта возможны, в математизированной литературе скорее "не имеет форму". "Не имеет формы" это про медузу какую-нибудь.

Хотя еще лучше просто переделать фразу. "Рамка - не прямоугольная". Или "форма рамки не прямоугольник (не является прямоугольником)". Как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность! Пожалуй, можно написать "не является прямоугольником", без всякой "формы" ;-))

Comment: Задачку потом огласите, OK? Хотя бы приватно. Очень уж странное условие насчет "непрямоугольной рамки". Напоминает анекдот про охотника на носеров.

Comment: Да нет, задачка обычная, просто рамка - это _разность_ двух прямоугольников. Насчет приватности непонятно: где взять адрес?

Comment: behemothus<at>mail.ru
Всё равно странно звучит.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, Вы не случайно обратили внимание на отрицательную частицу, ведь известно, что глагол с частицей НЕ управляет родительным, а не винительным падежом, особенно если управляемое слово означает отвлеченое понятие. Слово "форма" вполне относится к таким понятиям, так что, по-моему, правильно "не имеет формы треугольника"

Comment: Виктор1799, вы упускаете, что речь идёт об условии математической задачки. Я с вами соглашусь, если вы хоть в одном математизированном тектсе найдёте управление "не имеет" с двумя родительными подряд. 
Эта конструкция всегда вдечет двусмысленность, но математика подоных вольностей просто не прощает.

Comment: @виктор1799, да, формально я с Вами согласна, потому мне и не понравилась моя фраза. Но предложенный Вами вариант как-то не звучит... В общем, я ушла от проблемы, использовав совет @behemothus.  

PS Кажется, у Зощенко в рассказе описывалась подобная проблема. Как написать "пять кочерег" или "кочергей"?... В результате выписали две заявки: на две кочерги и на три кочерги ;-))

Comment: Вообще-то в [орригинале][1] все гораздо смешнее.

[1] http://ruslit.traumlibrary.net/book/zoschenko-ss07-04/zoschenko-ss07-04.html#work083